# Phantom Border on Element

Tags: html, css

I have a filled circle and a child element. I want the child ele to be 'attached' to the circle on the left. But I don't want this ele to have a visible border on its right edge.

I'm not sure why, but when these two eles are overlapped, the child ele has this faint kind of dashed border on the right.

```css
body {
  height: 900px;
  width: 1600px;
  zoom: 500%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  /*   border: solid 3px black; */
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.arc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 29%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translate(-68%, 15%) rotate(-24deg);
  border-radius: 100% 0% 0% 100%;
  /* Changing the last num to 0 gets rid
     of the phantom border..? */
  border-width: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  /* Padding 1px works to get rid of it when the element isnt rotated */
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Phantom Border]

https://codepen.io/CoreyBuckley/pen/ZEWKMaZ

Help on why this is occurring and how to get rid of it is much appreciated!

Comment: try to add padding:1px to .arc

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, that works when the element has no rotation to it. But it seems there's still a faint partial border when it's rotated. Should have been more clear, my bad. I've updated the codepen & post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else works hide it indirectly with a pseudo element, matching the colour at the edge  seems to sort out what appears to be an aliasing problem  Edit: I checked setting DPI scaling to 100% it doesnt appear to be linked with that.

```
.arc:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```